# Dataframe : GroupBy by list of column names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with multiple columns and a List of column names.

I want to process my Dataframe by grouping it according to my list.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do :

```
val tagList = List("col1","col3","col5")

var tagsForGroupBy = tagList(0)

if(tagList.length>1){
     for(i <- 1 to tagList.length-1){
              tagsForGroupBy = tagsForGroupBy+","+tags(i)
     }
}

// df is a Dataframe with schema (col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
df.groupBy("col0",tagsForGroupBy)
```

I understand why it does not work, but I don't know how to make it work.

What is the best solution to do that ?

EDIT :

Here is a more complete example of what I am doing (including SCouto solution) :

I have my tagList that contains some column names ("col3","col5"). I also want to include "col0" and "col1" in my groupBy, independently of my list.
After my groupBy and my aggregations, I want to select all columns used for group By and the new columns from aggregation.

```
val tagList = List("col3","col5")

val tmpListForGroup = new ListBuffer[String]()
val tmpListForSelect = new ListBuffer[String]()
tmpListForGroup +=tagList (0)
tmpListForSelect +=tagList (0)

for(i <- 1 to tagList .length-1){
    tmpListForGroup +=(tagList (i))
    tmpListForSelect +=(tagList (i))
}

tmpListForGroup +="col0"
tmpListForGroup +="col1"
tmpListForSelect +="aggValue1"
tmpListForSelect +="aggValue2"

// df is a Dataframe with schema (col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
df.groupBy(tmpListForGroup.head,tmpListForGroup.tail:_*)
  .agg(
      [aggFunction].as("aggValue1"),
      [aggFunction].as("aggValue1"))
  )
  .select(tmpListForSelect .head,tmpListForSelect .tail:_*)
```

This code do exactly what I want, but it look very ugly and complicated for something that (I think) should be simple.

Is there another solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

When sending column names as Strings, groupBy receives a column as first parameter and a sequence of them as second:

```
def groupBy(col1: String,cols: String*)
```

So you need to send two arguments and convert the second one to a sequence:

This will work fine for you:

```
df.groupBy(tagsForGroupBy.head, tagsForGroupBy.tail:_*)
```

Or if you want to separete col0 from the list as in your example:

```
df.groupBy("col0", tagsForGroupBy:_*)
```

Comment: Thanks, this work well, but in my case it's not a really conveniant solution. I wonder if there is a more 'pretty' way.
I will add more details in my post.